# Group validator not kicking in after Angular Reactive Form patchValue

Tags: angular, angular-validation, angular-reactive-forms, angular-daterangepicker

I'm using [mydatepicker](https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker) with the following homemade helper class:

```js
import {AbstractControl, FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';

export const dateRangeValidator = (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: boolean} => {
 const start = control.get('start');
 const end = control.get('end');
 if (!start || !end) {
  return null;
 }
 if (!start.value || !end.value) {
  return {required: true};
 }
 return start.value.jsdate < end.value.jsdate ? null : {invalid: true};
};

export const createDateRangeGroup = (fb: FormBuilder) => {
 return fb.group({
  start: null,
  end: null
 }, { validator: dateRangeValidator});
};

export const setDateRangeGroupDates = (dates: AbstractControl, start: Date, end: Date) => {
 dates.patchValue({
  start: {
   date: {
    year: start.getFullYear(),
    month: start.getMonth() + 1,
    day: start.getDate()
   }
  },
  end: {
   date: {
    year: end.getFullYear(),
    month: end.getMonth() + 1,
    day: end.getDate()
   }
  }
 });
};
```

`createDateRangeGroup` is being used within the component as follows:

```js
this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
  dates: createDateRangeGroup(this.fb)
});
setDateRangeGroupDates(this.formGroup.get('dates'), new Date(2017, 10, 1), new Date(2017, 10, 10));
```

I can see on the screen that the dates are set correctly. However, when I try to `console.log(this.formGroup.get('dates'));` it clearly shows an error of `{invalid: true}` even though if I just reselect the exact same dates from the dropdown the group becomes valid automatically.

What am I not doing?

Comment: and what shows console.log(start.value.jsdate)

Comment: OnInit. The whole code for creating the form and patching the value is in OnInit

Comment: I am not sure it was the answer... I meant when you place  console.log(start.value.jsdate) just before return  start.value.jsdate, what it shows?

Comment: Now I see what you mean, sorry. It shows `undefined` indeed.

Comment: Why don't you remove .jsdate, like return start.value< end.value ? null : {invalid: true};

Comment: That doesn't work because the `value` object refers to a custom `mydatepicker` object that's not comparable in that way. However, you're right, the problem is the properties of the internal object (jsdate, epoc, etc.) that remain `undefined` after using `patchValue`. I will have to compare the date manually I guess.

Comment: Check also if you are updating (patchvalue) with the correct format (date: ...)

Comment: Thank you, but if I weren't, the correct date would have not been logged (which is the case when I log `start.value` only) and it would have not appeared in the component at runtime.